# passing props from parent component to child and using in redux form connect

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

TypeError: Cannot read property 'status ' of undefined

but on parent component i am passing status as props. why i am not able to get this.props.status here ?

```
 class App extends Component{
   render(){
      return (
       <div>
         <childComponent 
           status={true}
         />
       <div>

     )
    }
  }
```

ChildComponent.js

```
 class childComponent extends Component{
   render(){
    console.log("props passed", this.props.status) // getting true 
    return(

   )

  }
}


export default reduxForm({
  form: 'wizard', 
  destroyOnUnmount: false, 
  forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true,
  enableReinitialize: this.props.status ? true : false, // error happening
})(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(childComponent)
);
```

Related to this question [Realted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54122839/redux-form-data-not-persisting-once-componentunmounts)

Comment: Can you create demo?

Comment: where i can create demo

Comment: Can you share your parent component code?

Comment: updated the code. basically access the props outside of the class component

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS: Can you create a runnable example at CodePen?

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS kindly share the code implementation of the Parent component this will make us understand how are you calling child parent in the parent. So we may identify the mistake you are making in passing that status prop.

Comment: @HaiderAliAnjum updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You just have access to `this.props` inside the `childComponent` class. Outside won't be possible to access them.

If you need to change `enableReinitialize` parameter or any other parameter dynamically, maybe this link will help you. 
https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/603#issuecomment-239543148